# Volume of the projection of a parallelotope onto an hyperplane

Tags: geometry, fourier-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $n\in\mathbb N^*$. We consider $\mathbb R^n$ with its euclidean structure.
Let's begin with some notations :

- $C_n = [-1/2,1/2]^n$ is the unit cube in $\mathbb R^n$
- $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ denotes the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$.
- For $\xi \in \mathbb S^{n-1}$ we denote $H(\xi)$ the $(n-1)$-hyperplane $H(\xi) = \{\xi\}^{\bot}$
- $\Pi(\xi)$ denotes the orthegonal projection of $C_n$ onto the hyperplane $H(\xi)$.
- $v_{n-1}(X)$ denotes the $(n-1)$ volume of $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ a $(n-1)$-dimensionnal set.

---

**So here's the problem:**

We consider a parallelotope $P$ (i.e. $P = M(C_n)$ for $M\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$). What is the maximum of $v_{n-1}(\Pi(\xi))$ and wich is the $\xi$ that give this maximum?

---

**What I did so far:**

Nothing successful

---

**Difficulties encountered:**

- How to extent the result for $C_n$ to parallelotopes?

EDIT: thanks to a comment, I know that an assumption that I made was false.

Comment: The "volume" of orthogonal projection is not the same as the "volume" of the intersection. Let's say $n = 3$ and $\xi$ is along the direction $(1,1,1)$. The projection of $C_3$ to $H(\xi)$ is a hexagon of side $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ while $H(\xi) \cap C_3$ is a hexagon of side $\sqrt{\frac12}$.

Comment: @achillehui you are right... Thanks